# Who controls the StackLinguist's tweeting?

Tags: support, marketing

There is a twitter account which regularly tweets questions from this site. Who controls this tweeting? Is it random, automatic, or controlled by some moderator? If automatic, what determines which question gets tweeted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Twitter.com/StackLinguist](http://twitter.com/stacklinguist) tweets interesting questions every so often automatically. I emphasize *interesting* because Twitter is not meant to be an arbitrary RSS Feed.

The feed is designed to publish the most interesting questions from this site every three hours — without ever repeating themselves.

[**Twitter Question Feeds for Stack Exchange**](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/twitter-question-feeds-for-stack-exchange/)

The Twitter account currently tweets:

- per-site blog posts ([if you create one](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/))
- chat events, if started by a moderator
- interesting questions on the site
- bountied questions
- interesting answers of +3 or better
- unanswered questions of +3 or better
- particularly hot meta questions (not [support](/questions/tagged/support) or [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) though)